# set size for table column name

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I have a table where i have some column, now i want to set the size of my column names. By default it is small now.

This is my column names---

```
<tr class="something">
  <th> Name </th>
  <th>Phone</th>
</tr>
```

script which does not work----

```
        <script> 
        $(".something") th {
           font - size: 2em; /* em is relative to the parent font size */
           font - weight: bold;
       }
       </script>
```

now using bootstrap or basic html how can i set the column name **bold and big**.

I know there are thousand of solution to solve this problem, although i want to know how it be solved.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: hi first of all you are mixing two different things that are css and script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `font-size` and `font-weight` for big and bold size of column name.

```js
// Alternate jQuery Solution since you use Twitter Bootstrap

var header = $('.something th');
header.css('font-size', '2em'); 
header.css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

```css
/* Simple CSS Solution */

.something th {
  font-size: 2em; /* em is relative to the parent font size */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="something">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the script is not working i have update my question, can you kindly have a look

Comment: Your code is not CSS but JavaScript. It is incorrect as well. Any reason you want to use JS instead of CSS? :)

Comment: Check this if you are using Bootstrap: https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/

Comment: Please let me know why this was down voted. I see no reason why, maybe I am wrong. Seems like the down voter mistook the answer with latest question edit.

Comment: @ManojKumar yup sorry dude i just have mistaken the answer with latest question edit and now trying to upvote that but i can't how can i do upvote for that.?